# Do not clear inputs after submit

Tags: javascript

Is there some kind of trick to keep input data after `Form.submit();` Or must I fill it manually?

`Form.submit();` clears all fields

Comment: Are you using a library, i.e. jQuery?

Answer (score 3):

The form will clear by default when the page refreshes.

There's a couple of things you could:

1. use ajax to post your form to the server, thus eliminating the page
   refresh
2. re-bind the data to the form fields on the server side after
   processing
3. there's other options too but i'm trying to be brief

Answer (score 0):

You have to fill it in. however, I do not think you can do this with Javascript since form data is posted to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Use the simple serialize() to get the url and then use the ajax post or get as you wish. Here are the links which will help you:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/